# Generation of all subsets of strings for a given string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, time-complexity

I want a code to generate all the subsets of strings of the given string.

I tried this on my own and came up with this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
    String text = "1234";
    int n = text.length();
    String k = "";
    for(int i=0;i < Math.pow(2, n);i++){
        k = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        while(k.length() != n){
            k = "0"+k;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j=0;j<k.length();j++){
            if(k.charAt(j) == '1'){
                sb.append(text.charAt(j));
            }
        }
    //  System.out.println(String.format("%04d",
    //      Integer.parseInt(k)));
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Duration:" + duration);
}
```

But this is a horrible O(n^2) algorithm so I was looking for a better solution and found this:

```
public static void comb2(String s) { 
    comb2("", s);
}
private static void comb2(String prefix, String s) {
    System.out.println(prefix);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        comb2(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(i + 1));
    }
}  


// read in N from command line, and print all subsets among N elements
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String alphabet = "1234";
   comb2(alphabet);
   System.out.println();
}
```

The output generated is :
1
12
123
1234
124
13
134
14
2
23
234
24
3
34
4

Although the code is working fine. I was debugging it to understand the logic. I get how 1, 12, 123, 1234 are being generated but after that is not so clear. Can tell me whats going on here?

Comment: You need to understand what recursion is for that. Have appropriate breakpoints and debug your code. You can discover the magic of recursion :)

Comment: Well thats what I was doing. I got until 1234 was display and then it went on removing digits from the string until it got back to 12 and then added 4 to it. I am confused as how that can happen though.

Comment: BTW, this is also -- to use your terminology -- a *horrible O(n^2) algorithm*. Given that you are printing out `O(n^2)` characters, you cannot do better than quadratic complexity.

Comment: The total number of substrings of a string of n characters = n*(n+1)/2 ~ O(N^2). I don't think you can get better than that time complexity.

Comment: @NPE can you give a link to any better algorithm?

Comment: It seems you are creating all the subsets not all stubstring 14,134 etc are not substrings of the original string

Comment: By the way your program is not `horrible O(n^2)` but rather O(2^n). Haven't looked at the code but a set with n size will have ~2^n subsets!

Comment: Yes. that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to understand is how the comb2 method works. Basically, it calls itself. This is called *recursion*.

When you call comb2("1234"), the result is a call to comb2("","1234").

- comb2("","1234") prints "" (which has no effect), then starts a loop
  through the end of the string ("234"). The first thing it does in
  this loop is call comb2("1","234").
- comb2("1", "234") prints "1", then starts a loop through the end of
  the string ("234"). The first thing it does in this loop is call
  comb2("12","34").
- comb2("12", "34") prints "12", then starts a loop through the end of
  the string ("34"). The first thing it does in this loop is call
  comb2("123","4").
- comb2("123", "4") prints "123", then starts a loop through the end of
  the string ("4"). The first thing it does in this loop is call
  comb2("1234","").
- comb2("1234", "") prints "1234", then starts a loop through the end
  of the string (""). Since there is nothing to do, it returns
  immediately to its caller : comb2("123","4").
- comb2("123", "4") now goes to the next step in its loop. Since there
  is none, it returns.
- comb2("12", "34") now goes to the next step in its loop. It calls
  comb2("124","").
- comb2("124", "") prints "124", then starts a loop through the end of
  the string (""). There is nothing to do, so it returns immediately.

This is how you get from "1234" to "124". Hopefully, from there, you shoud be able to understand the whole execution.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is `comb2(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(i + 1))`, to understand it better please build an analogy from this statement with the cartesian product, I think this solves every thing. Indeed your'e creating all substrings starting the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a moment's noodling brought me:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class subs {
    static List<String> allInitialSubstrings(String s) {
        List<String> r = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            r.add(s.substring(0, i+1));
        }
        return r;
    }

    static List<String> allSubstrings(String s) {
        List<String> r = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            r.addAll(allInitialSubstrings(s.substring(i)));
        }
        return r;
    }
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println(allSubstrings(args[0]));
    }
}

~ $ javac subs.java 
~ $ java subs 12345
[1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 2, 23, 234, 2345, 3, 34, 345, 4, 45, 5]
```

If you want subsets instead of substrings, it's too much a pain in the neck for me to write it in an archaic language like Java, but here it is in the only-slightly elderly Python:

```
def allSubsets(s):
  if len(s):
    car = s[0]
    cdr = allSubsets(s[1:])
    return set([car + b for b in cdr]).union(cdr)
  else:
    return set([""])

allSubsets("12345")
```

Comment: beautiful answer, but does I am still not clear about the recursive example that I posted.

Comment: That'll teach me to just read the summary and not the question itself...  Let me look.

Comment: Yeah, that recursive algorithm isn't quite right.  Try it with "12345" -- it produces 33 "substrings", when only 15 exist.

Comment: I updated the post, I am running it for generating the subsets not the substrings

Comment: "All possible subsets" is homologous to "the binary patterns of the numbers zero to 2^n - 1".  0000 means empty set, 0001 means only the first character, and so on.

Comment: The answer is wrong. The OP asks for all subsets. Note you are missing the subset 15. The expected number of subsets to be produced is 2^5=32 for this given example, and not 15 as you have

Comment: @amit - When I wrote the answer, the question was about substrings.

Comment: Haven't noticed there was such a radical edit to the question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This program should work correctly

```
public static void getAllSubStrings(char[] chars,int start, Set allSubStrings){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(start==chars.length){
        return;
    }
    for(int i=start;i<chars.length;i++){
        sb.append(chars[i]);
        allSubStrings.add(sb.toString());
    }
    getAllSubStrings(chars, start+1, allSubStrings);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set s = new TreeSet();
    getAllSubStrings("12345".toCharArray(), 0, s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Generated output is `[1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 2, 23, 234, 2345, 3, 34, 345, 4, 45, 5]`

From what I think this is still going to be O(n2) because it will run n+(n-1)+(n-2)... times which is n(n+1)/2 I don't think you can get better than that

Comment: Shouldnt the ans be something like this?
12
123
1234
124
13
134
14
2
23
234
24
3
34
4

Comment: @user3335993 No, 134,13 etc are not substring of 1234 in any programming language. There is a difference in finding all subsets of a string and all substrings of a string. Please find my comments in the original questions. Only if `"1234".indexOf("134")>-1 then 134 is substring of 1234.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have been clear while asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without any for loop, cleaner version with same logic would be:

```
public static void printSubSets(String s){
    subSetsHelper(s, "");
}

private static void subSetsHelper(String s, String acc) {
    if (s.equals("")){
        System.out.println(acc);
        return;
    }
    subSetsHelper(s.substring(1), acc + s.charAt(0)); // accumulate 1st character
    subSetsHelper(s.substring(1), acc); // do not
}
```

> printSubSets("abc");
>   abc
>   ab
>   ac
>   a
>   bc
>   b
>   c
>   ""